# Poisson distribution in R mixdist package

Tags: r

I think my data might be described by a sum of Poisson distributions and I found out about `mixdist` package for R. I managed to fit gamma and lnorm distributions, but I can't figure out how to use Poisson. I tried with the example data first:

```r
    library(mixdist) 
    data(poisdat)
    data(poispar)
    plot.mixdata(poisdat) #this works
    fitp<-mix(poisdat, coef(poispar), "pois") #this doesn't
```

but I get an error `Error in if (usecondit & ncol(mixdat) - 2 != k) stop("Conditional data are not consistent with mixpar.") : argument is of length zero`

How to get a working example of mixdist and Poisson?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this:

```r
mix(poisdat, poispar, "pois", constr = mixconstr(consigma = "POIS"))
```

Simply `mix(poisdat, poispar, "pois")` gives an Error:

> Error in testconstr(mixdat, mixpar, dist, constr) : 
>     Poisson needs consigma = POIS.

thas why this `constr` parameter.

Comment: thank you, this works. I couldn't hit on the right syntax because there are so few examples around